# Help Me Understand an Example From Schilling's Book: Measures, Integrals and Martingales.

Tags: measure-theory

In the first chapter of his book Measures, Integrals and Martingales, Schilling demonstrates

[how dividing up a circle into infinite triangles can produce the area of a circle (3).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI33p.jpg)

["However, finite additivity is not enough for this and we have to use instead infinitely many pieces: \sigma - additivity. Thus ... " (Schilling 3):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGL1l.jpg)

The example question on page 5 then asks to find the area of a circle with radius *r*. Here is the solution to that question that can found in his [solutions manual](http://www.motapa.de/measures_integrals_and_martingales/solutions-mims-2ed.pdf):

[Solution to example 1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b1hr.png)

From the solution, I understand everything except where the $\dfrac{2\pi}{ 2^j}$ in the denominator in $\dfrac{\sin(\frac{2\pi}{2^j})}{ \frac{2\pi}{2^j}}$ came from.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack! You should include the necessary information for the problem within the question, rather than distributed in several links. Preferably, it should be written in MathJax notation, but you should at least consider including the important parts of those links as images.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Darsen. Unfortunately, since I'm a new user, Math Exchange won't allow me to directly post pictures until I have earned 5 tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $\ 2^j\ $  non-overlapping triangles, each of area $\ \frac{r^2}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^j}\right)\ $, so the total area they cover is $\ 2^{j-1}r^2\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^j}\right)\ $. But since $\ 2^{j-1}=$$\left(\frac{2^j}{2\pi}\right)\pi=$$\frac{\pi}{\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^j}\right)}\ $, this total area can be written as
$$
\pi r^2 \frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^j}\right)}{\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^j}\right)}\ .
$$

**Response to query from OP below**

The reason why Schilling writes the total area of the triangles in the above form is so that when he takes the limit as $\ j\rightarrow\infty\ $, he can cite the theorem $\ \displaystyle\lim_\limits{\theta\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1\ $ to get
$$
\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty} \pi r^2 \frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^j}\right)}{\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^j}\right)}=\pi r^2\ .
$$
Note that he has not ultimately multiplied the expression for the area by *anything*; he has simply rewritten the factor $\ 2^{j-1}\ $ as the completely equivalent fraction $\ \frac{\pi}{\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^j}\right)}\ $.

Comment: But why isn't 2^(j-1) equal to just PI? If 2^j = 2PI, since all triangles cover the entire 360 degrees, then why is it necessary to multiply by the (2^j/2PI)

Comment: Since your question assumes an erroneous premise, I'm guessing you've misstated it.   If $\ j\ $ is an integer, then $\ 2^{j-1}=2,4,8,\dots\ $ etc. for $\ j=2,3,4,\dots\ $, and can *never* be equal to $\ \pi=3.14159\dots\ $.   I'm also guessing you're confused about the angles in the triangles' vertices at the centre of the circle. The angle in that vertex of every triangle is $\ \frac{2\pi}{2^j}\ $ (radians), and since there are $\ 2^j\ $ triangles, the total of those angles is $\ 2^j\left(\frac{2\pi}{2^j}\right)=$$2\pi\ $ radians, or $360$ degrees.